# Magento 2 how to Add Facebook Pixel code?

Tags: magento2, facebook

How to add facebook pixel code in Magento 2.Is there any free module is available or do we need to create custom module for that?

If anyone implemented this please share ideas.

Comment: you can use this extension   https://marketplace.magento.com/apptrian-facebook-pixel.html

Comment: Ok @RakeshDonga,Thanks for sharing,did you use it and working or we need any customization?

Comment: i have used in magento1 same extension but i have not in requirement to customization